# How to avoid encoded XSS injection in web application using java?

Tags: java, security, xss, websecurity

In our application we are currently using a `Jsoup` jar to filter all the XSS injected scripts.

But when the input scripts are encoded and passed the `Jsoup` jar is not filtering it out.

Current Code:

```java
public static String stripXSS(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
                
    String jsoupValue = Jsoup.clean(value, Whitelist.none());
    return Parser.unescapeEntities(jsoupValue, true);
}
```

Scenario 1 using the following payload:

```
"><script>alert(document.domain)</script>
```

In this scenario, the `Jsoup` filter is working fine and filtering the script.

Scenario 2, using the following line:

```java
urlencode(htmlencode(payload))
```

Output with the HTML encoded:

```
&#x22;&#x3e;&#x3c;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3e;&#x61;&#x6c;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x33;&#x29;&#x3c;&#x2f;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3e;
```

Final url encoded:

```
%26%23%78%32%32%3b%26%23%78%33%65%3b%26%23%78%33%63%3b%26%23%78%37%33%3b%26%23%78%36%33%3b%26%23%78%37%32%3b%26%23%78%36%39%3b%26%23%78%37%30%3b%26%23%78%37%34%3b%26%23%78%33%65%3b%26%23%78%36%31%3b%26%23%78%36%63%3b%26%23%78%36%35%3b%26%23%78%37%32%3b%26%23%78%37%34%3b%26%23%78%32%38%3b%26%23%78%33%33%3b%26%23%78%32%39%3b%26%23%78%33%63%3b%26%23%78%32%66%3b%26%23%78%37%33%3b%26%23%78%36%33%3b%26%23%78%37%32%3b%26%23%78%36%39%3b%26%23%78%37%30%3b%26%23%78%37%34%3b%26%23%78%33%65%3b
```

When the final encoded Url is passed, the `Jsoup` filter is not filtering the input payload correctly.

Any suggestions on how to use the `Jsoup` jar for this situation?, or any other logic to prevent this type of XSS injection?

Comment: What's the threat model for this? In what scenario do you think the URL-encoded string will cause an XSS issue? Are you URL decoding it before displaying it? If so, you should be passing the URL-decoded string to the filter.

Comment: @TimMoore We are not doing any explicit decoding but the jsoup jar and jsoup code mentioned above is doing the decoding .. Not sure why jsoup is doing the decoding .. Any methods to turn off the decoding in jsoup jar